# Could Opa be used for mobile and tablet development?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile, opa

Could Opa be used for iOS and Android apps on tablets/phones?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to build *native* application for those mobile platform.

But Opa is perfect to write rich and interactive *web applications*.

Their is some built-in functions in the Opa standard library specific to mobile, for example `iphone customizers` to add an icon and a start-up image:
http://doc.opalang.org/#!/value/stdlib.core.web.resource/Resource/iphone_customizer

Comment: Indeed, also keep in mind that this is a topic that we are thinking about and it's *very* likely than one day (cannot be more specific on that, I'm afraid) support for writing native mobile apps will be added (most likely by leveraging a framework such as PhoneGap or Appcelerator).

Answer (score 1):

You can check out a fork of OpaDo which is enhanced for iPhone/iPad and possibly other mobile platforms:
https://github.com/creatrice/OpaDo